# Cherrypy with Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, cherrypy

I installed CherryPy with pip3 (Python 3.4) and it installs successfully but when I go into the interactive shell and do import cherrypy I get this

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 12 2018, 22:25:49) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cherrypy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/CherryPy-18.5.0-py3.4.egg/cherrypy/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from ._cperror import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/CherryPy-18.5.0-py3.4.egg/cherrypy/_cperror.py", line 129, in <module>
    from more_itertools import always_iterable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/more_itertools/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .more import *  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/more_itertools/more.py", line 2505

               ^
SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target
```

Do I need a different version of CherryPy?  I've tried googling the error but I'm not sure why the package isn't just working.  I've used CherryPyfor awhile but never had this type of problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if support for Python 3.4 has been dropped somewhere between CherryPy 17.4 and CherryPy 18.0 (around September 2018)

See: https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/commit/855b4341f6bc58dba692675817a09e82f8a4b287

> Drop support for Python 3.4.

That matches the description on pypi, where 17.4.2 seems to be the latest version that supports Python 3.4 - compare the requirement listing for 17.4.2 with 18.0.0

From https://pypi.org/project/CherryPy/17.4.2/

> Requires: Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*

From https://pypi.org/project/CherryPy/18.0.0/ (same for https://pypi.org/project/CherryPy/18.5.0/)

> Requires: Python >=3.5

Seeing that your log states `CherryPy-18.5.0-py3.4.egg` means that you must indeed install a different version if you plan to use CherryPy with Python 3.4